# Testing ApplePay SDK

Tags: ios, ios8, applepay

Im trying to integrate ApplePay SDK in one of my apps. When Im going through the documentation I couldn't find how to test the application in test environment. I don't want to use my actual credit card. Any one have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The actual iOS APIs for Apple Pay produce an encrypted piece of payment data, which contains the information needed to make the charge. It doesn't matter if you use your own card or not, because you're never actually making a charge. All you're doing is re-wrapping the card information into a secure format ready for processing. You can either decrypt this data yourself, or send it to a payment processor (such as Stripe or Braintree), who will decrypt it and charge it for you. If you're using a payment processor they will have their own test environments.